# is it possible to add a variable to path while inserting a blob

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to add a variable to path while inserting a blob
I've tried this code but unfortunately it does not work as I want :(

```
declare @i int
declare @test varbinary(max)
set @i=1
set @test=(select * FROM OPENROWSET 
(BULK ''K:\test\1'+'@'+'.xml'', SINGLE_BLOB)myfile)
insert tab1 values (@test)
```

A1
@David
Hi David,
Thank you for your advice. Blob output shows what I want to achive, but then I need to insert that output @blob to table and it is completly different.

Code from screen 1

```
declare @i int = 2
declare @file varchar(2000) = concat('C:\xml\EmployeeWorkTime',@i,'.xml');
declare @blob varbinary(max)
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = concat(N'select @blob = BulkColumn FROM 
OPENROWSET(BULK ''',@file,''', SINGLE_BLOB) myfile')
insert [dbo].[tab1] values (convert(Varbinary(MAX),@sql))
```

Screen 1[image]
Screen 2[image]

A2
After select @BLOB there should be insert and this solve my problem :) Thank you again @David

```
(...)
select @blob
insert tab1 values(@blob)
```

Comment: It's always good to list the error(s) you get, what the current result is, and what the expected result is. *It does not work as i want* doesn't help because we don't know what you want.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near 'K:'.

Comment: I want to add a variable  @i into path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OPENROWSET does not support expressions or variables for the filename.  You can use dynamic SQL instead.  Like this:

```
declare @i int = 1

declare @file varchar(2000) = concat('K:\test\file',@i,'.xml');

--set @file = 'c:\temp\a.xml'

declare @blob varbinary(max)

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = concat(N'select @blob = BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''',@file,''', SINGLE_BLOB) myfile')

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@blob varbinary(max) output', @blob = @blob output

select @blob
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Blob output shows what I want to achive, but then I need to insert that output @blob to table and after insert it is completely different.